# Android keyboard crashes continuously

Tags: keyboard, crashes

Since this afternoon the Android keyboard crashes continuously on my phone, Samsung Galaxy S2. I have Avatarrom installed. I tried to delete the Dalvik Cache (cache/dalvik cache and data/dalvik cache), restarted the phone, but that didn't help.

Today I installed BTSync (Bittorrent Sync) on my phone. I don't know if it has anything to do with these problems.

(See update below - I have disabled App Protector!) I have App Protector installed, and it protects the system menu, so I can't open that. I can't open the Playstore to download SSHdroid or some other tool that will allow me to remotely access the phone. I cannot paste passwords into App Protector. I don't have a second keyboard installed.

I do have ES File Explorer installed, without protection, and can use that to clear the cache or remove files. It has root access.

Rom Toolbox is installed without protection. I can open the App Manager in Room Toolbox, but cannot remove App Protector. Freezing the app doesn't work either. Because the keyboard crashes so often it's difficult to do anything.

So I'm wondering what options are left for me. I have lockeck myself out it seems. Of course I can install a new rom, but if possible I want to avoid that route. What suggestions do you have?

---

UPDATE

I managed to disable App Protector. I copied a text file with the password for App Protector to the phone. I copied the text, and I could copy the password and that worked, so I disabled it immediately.

I have installed Thumb Keyboard, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Avatarrom with the 4.0.10 Nightly update. That fixed the problem. The keyboard crashes are history.

Comment: *Accept* your answer with the green tick/check mark, so other visitors can see your problem is solved.